# Input element that allowes only number with decimals, with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to create an input element that:

- Holds a number (string or actual number doesn't matter).
- You shall not be able to enter anything else but numbers and a dot(.).
- You are allowed to enter two decimals.
- If no decimals are entered, two decimals (i.e. .00) shall be added to the number when leaving the input element (on-blur).
- I'm working with AngularJS (1.2) and watch $valid and $invalid on the containing form.
- The input is valid when the value is a number with two decimals and the value is larger than 0.

I have tried to use:

```
<input ng-model="price" type="number" ng-blur="addDecimals()"/>

$scope.addDecimals = function(){
  $scope.price = $scope.price.toFixed(2);
}
```

But then I can't add zeroes as decimals (.00). As toFixed() returns a string, the value is not allowed in the input and it becomes empty.

I have also tried to use

```
<input type="text" ng-model="price" ng-blur="addDecimals()" ng-change="changed()" /> 

$scope.changed = function(){
    // removes all charachters but numbers and one dot (.);
    // examples: 
    //  if value is '1a.t9' it will be changed to '1.9'
    //  if value is 'qwe' it will be changed to ''
    //  if value is 4 it will not be changed.
    $scope.price = removeAllCharsButNumbersAndDot($scope.price);
}

$scope.addDecimals = function(){
   if(parseFloat($scope.price) > 0) 
     $scope.price = $scope.price.toFixed(2);
   else
     $scope.price = "";
}
```

With this solution [form].$valid will be set to true if the value '0' is entered. [form].$valid will be set to false only when the user leaves the input element (on-blur) which is kind of ugly.

I have tried to use ng-pattern="/^\s*(?=.*[1-9])\d*(?:.\d{1,2})?\s*$/", but then ng-change will not fire.

Comment: Text input element to invalid? Can you please tell what you really want to achieve.

Comment: You can just do a `type="number"` and add a `min="0"` to the input

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-validate. Ui-validate is great for this. Example:

```
<input type="number" ng-model="priceModel" ui-validate=" 'checkPriceModel($value)' ">

//Controller:

$scope.checkPriceModel = function(value){
  return value <= 0;
}
```

Comment: But if I don't want to have type="number" ?

Comment: @Theresa you can use type="text" too

Comment: Sorry, commented wrong answer :-) Thank's for the tip though, but I want to avoid adding another library.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need ng-change for this. You can just rewrite your html like this.

```
<form name="theForm" id="theForm">
  <input id="priceId" type="number" 
    name="priceName" ng-model="priceModel" required min="0" />
  <span class="error" ng-show="theForm.priceName.$error.number">
       Not valid number!
  </span>
</form>
```

You can read more about it here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bnumber%5D

Comment: Problem is that I always want to display two decimals (i.e.: x.00, unless decimals are entered by user). I use toFixed(2) on the value for this,, but as toFixed returns a string, that value will not be displayed in the input if type is number. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
<form name="theForm" id="theForm">
<input ng-change="changed()" id="priceId" type="number" min="1" name="priceName" ng-model="priceModel" required />
</form>
```

is the easiest (without extra modules)

Answer (score 0):

If i am getting it right, you can try following

```
<form name="appTest">
<div
     ng-class="{ 'has-error': appTest.app.$touched && appTest.app.$invalid }">
    <input type="text" ng-model="vm.text" name="app" ng-pattern={define your pattern}>
    </select>
</div>
```

If its invalid, 'has-error' class will get applied.